# How to use int in place of T in a Java generic method?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I have this method that I just want to let it accept a multi dimensional array of any type.

Here is the current code:

```
public static <T> T[] aMethod(T[][] multiDimentionalArray) {
    return null;
}
```

and when I try it out with something like:

```
int[][] a = new int[][] {{1,2,3,4},{2}};
aMethod(a);
```

I keep getting an error to change the aMethod parameter type to int[][].. so why is this happening, don't I have generic type applied?

Comment: Your generic type `T` cannot be `int`, since an int is not an `Object`.

Comment: Generics only work for class types, not primitive types. (So you can't use `List<int>` for example.)

Comment: `int` is a primitive type and canot be used as an argument in generics (eG `List<int>` is not valid java). You need to use `Integer[][]` and it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use Integer instead of int, because `T` should be an Object, and `int` is a primitive type :

```
Integer[][] a = new Integer[][]{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2}};
```

If you want to pass an array of `int[][]`, in this case you have to change the signature of your method, to be :

```
public static <T> T[] aMethod(T[] multiDimentionalArray) {
```

---

But in case(I don't suggest this) to work with array or array you need to cast your value to help the compiler to understand what happen for example :

```
public static <T> void aMethod(T[] multiDimentionalArray) {
    for (int[] t : (int[][]) multiDimentionalArray) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t));
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright thanks, and how can I convert from int[][] to Integer[][]? I know this method  Arrays.stream(array).distinct().toArray(Integer[]::new); but it only does it for a single dimension array not multi.

Comment: that is as I mentioned before already changes a single dimensional array of int to integer, but I am asking for a method to convert multi dimensional array of int to a multi dimensional array of Integer..

Comment: @albertos please create a new question, and we will answer you, the question should be for one topic not many ;)

Comment: @albertos you can use `Integer[][] integers = Arrays.stream(array)
        .map(a -> Arrays.stream(a).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new))
        .toArray(Integer[][]::new);`

Answer (score 0):

You [cannot use a primitive type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#instantiate), such as `int`, as the concrete type for a generic method. You need to use something that inherits from `Object`, like the `Integer` type:

```
Integer[][] a = new Integer[][] {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2}};
aMethod(a);
```

The reason for this is that Java generics are implemented using [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genMethods.html) and any concrete type [will be replaced](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) with  their type bounds or `Object` if they are unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

See java [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html)

***Cannot Instantiate Generic Types with Primitive Types***

change to

```
Integer[][] a = new Integer[][] {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2}};
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
public static <T> T aMethod(T multiDimentionalArray) {
     return null;
}
```

This works for you.

Comment: nope that is not correct, wouldn't return a multidimensional array..

Comment: It does, because T is what you given to int[][].